# is it possible after native browser detection in your website to open it out in external browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, progressive-web-apps, native

I got inspired by google maps ,
When it detects native browser it suggest to use it in app
The detection process is simple but im not sure ,

**The question is :**

on ANDROID devices
How i can force my website users to exit that native browser and open it in default(external) browser

Google Chrome:

> googlechrome://domain

this is simple detection snippet

```
function isInFacebookApp() {
      return /FBAV/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    }

if (isInFacebookApp()) {
  // do somthing window.open("https://my-website.com");
} else {
  console.log("native browser not detected");
}`
```

Comment: I think you can use google chrome CustomTab for android

Comment: @ChiragThummar thank you so much my thought process pretty simple just so my users can install pwa after opening in external chrome browser also im targeting just android users so intent link  did what i needed

Answer (score 0):

After testing for little bit i found this and its working just fine

In my case **android** and default browser **google-chrome**

**// Use the 'intent:' link for Android**

```
  if (/Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    window.location.href = 'intent:https://your-website.com#Intent;end';
  } else {
    // For other platforms, use window.open with a fallback
    window.open('https://your-site.com');
  }
```